# free associative algebras as tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be $k$-algebras with $k$ a commutative ring. Suppose that the **free product** $A \cdot_k B$ is a free associative $k$-algebra of rank $n$. Does it imply that $A,B$ are both free associative $k$-algebras?

Working this sort of "factorization" problems in several different settings, I realized that there is no mention in the literature (which I have access) in this case and I am not able to prove it.

EDIT: The question is false if is considered the usual tensor product.

Comment: I would be surprised if a free associative algebra can be written as a tensor product in any nontrivial way at all.  Also, to be clear: Are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be $k$-algebras (and $A\otimes_k B$ a free associative $k$-algebra) for some commutative ring $k$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as if the converse is true, but it's not: the coproduct in associative algebras is the free product, not the tensor product, and if $A, B$ are free then $A \otimes_k B$ will almost never be free.

Comment: @eric wofsey: Yes. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I am OK with the fact that the converse is not true. My questions are phrased the way I can write them in a direct form. It is not based on the validity of the converse. If you want, you can rewrite it.

Comment: Just for the record: The tensor product of free associative algebras $k\langle  X\rangle\otimes_k k\langle  Y\rangle$ where $X,Y$ are sets is isomorphic to the quotient $k\langle X\cup Y\rangle/C$, where $C$ is the ideal generated by all commutators $[X_i,Y_j]$, $X_i\in X, Y_j\in Y$.